# Fix Input == null! error to Create an Image

Tags: java, input

I am trying to load a spritesheet, but it is not working. It gives an error Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

I saved the image into folders } res --> Textures --> sheets.png . I made sure the res folder is in the Class Folder by building a path.

Please help

```
        //  public class Game 
   private void init(){
    display = new Display(title, width, height);
    test = BufferedImageLoader.loadImage("/sheets.png");
    Assets.init();
} 

  private void render(){
    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);


    g.drawImage(test, x, 10, null);

    //End Drawing!
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
```

// public class BufferedImageLoader {

```
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path){
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(BufferedImageLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: if `res` is your resources folder (note this isn't the conventional resources folder eg `src/main/resources`) shouldn't it be `BufferedImageLoader.loadImage("Textures/sheets.png")`?

Comment: It didn't work. I am going to try using another approach. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Make a separate folder with all the images in the source folder. Then, use the link /folder name/ photo name . format (ex. "/Images/mario.png"). This way works.